# TypeScript Definition for Backbone.Syphon

Tags: typescript

I've come across an unusual hurdle with TypeScript regarding definitions. I've attempting to write a definition file for the (very simple) [Backbone.Syphon](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/) library. The Backbone.Syphon object contains only two methods, `serialize` and `deserialize`. However, I've been unable to successfully write a definition file.

My existing definition file is as follows (leaving off the deserialize for now, because its orthogonal to the question at hand):

```
define module Backbone
  class Syphon {
    serialize(view: Backbone.View, options: any): any;
  }
}
```

Yet, when attempting to use `Backbone.Syphon.serialize()` anywhere, the error I receive is:

`error TS2094: The property 'serialize' does not exist on value of type 'typeof Backbone.Syphon'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should look something like:

```
define module Backbone.Syphon {
    function serialize(view: Backbone.View, options: any): any;
    // function deserialize(/* etc */): any;

    class KeyExtractorSet {
        registerDefault(thing: ($el: any) => void): void;
    }

    module KeyExtractors {
        function register(name: string, thing: ($el: any) => any): void;
    }

    /* ... more ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, tried this out and you are quite right. Wasn't aware I could just declare a module directly with the dot notation - thanks!